# JavaScript code doesn't execute in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn programming from various online tutorials and I created flask server which predicts something. I also got the front-end with javascript but it wont run.  I don't know why. I don't know JS. I know python well but that's it.

I don't know that to do.

here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript", src="static/code.js"></script>

    <title>Heading</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <!--<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="static/final_v1.png" alt=""></a>-->
    <br>
    <div class="container main">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="holder">
    <h1 class='main_heading'> Some Machine learning model</h1>
    <h3>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <br>
    <div class="instructions">
      <h2>Instructions: </h2>
      <p>1. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      <p>2. Curabitur tincidunt orci non nunc sagittis euismod.</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Feature1:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input  class="form-control" id="feature1" placeholder=" Enter feature1" >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <h2 class="result"></h2>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small blue">

  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
    <div class="bottom">
      <p><a href="#">xyz | Status Prediction Demo</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->


  </body>
</html>
```

here is the JS file:

```
var feature1;

$(document).ready(function(){
  // fetch all DOM elements for the input
  feature1_ = document.getElementById("feature1");
  ;

});

$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
    alert('end')
    // on clicking submit fetch values from DOM elements and use them to make request to our flask API
    var feature1 = feature1_.value;


    if(feature1 == ""){
      // you may allow it as per your model needs
      // you may mark some fields with * (star) and make sure they aren't empty here
      alert("empty fields not allowed");
    }
    else{
      var requestURL = "http://127.0.0.1/predict?f1="+feature1;

      console.log(requestURL); // log the requestURL for troubleshooting
      $.getJSON(requestURL, function(data) {
        console.log(data); // log the data for troubleshooting
        prediction = data['json_key_for_the_prediction'];
      });
      // following lines consist of action that would be taken after the request has been read
      // for now i am just changing a <h2> tag's inner html using jquery
      // you may simple do: alert(prediction);
      alert(prediction)
      $(".result").html("Prediction is:" + prediction);

    }
  });
```

There is flask on the backend and js suppose to execute the link. 
I have no idea why this is not working
Could you help me please ?

Comment: Can you elaborate 'It won't run', could you please share the error you are getting.

Comment: Its a weird js ,you could have made it more simplified,I don't find the reason of getting `document.getElById` in `document.ready`,when you already have another event for the purpose

Comment: You have errors that https://validator.nu/ would detect

Comment: See if you have errors in console (Press F12 to open DevTools and go to Console tab)

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not definedcode.js:3:1
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/code.js:3

Comment: @AdBlu: Your button type is submit type but you are calling in javascript using id which was not defined in button. Please make button type and add id="submit". Submit button will reload page and till now not received response of HTTP call. Callback is canceled due to reload of page

Comment: @Dipti this is html button:           <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-default">Submit</button>
How can I modify it ?

Comment: @AdBlu: Yes for HTML button use <input type="button" id="button" class="button btn btn-default" value="Submit" name="Submit">

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are several things:

1. Your submit button is missing an id
2. Your submit button causes reload
3. Your callback will run before you get a response

Change your HTML to:

```html
<button id="submit" type="button" type="button" class="button btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

The `type` attribute will remove the reload and the added id will make your script recognize it.

These lines of code runs before you get a response:

```
alert(prediction)
$(".result").html("Prediction is:" + prediction);
```

Put them inside `getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(data) {
  console.log(data); // log the data for troubleshooting
  var prediction = data['json_key_for_the_prediction']; // <-- added `var`
  alert(prediction);
  $(".result").html("Prediction is:" + prediction);
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193859/discussion-on-answer-by-tzach-ovadia-javascript-code-doesnt-execute-in-the-brow).

Answer (score -2):

You're clearly new so I'm offering a strict/minimal test case file for you to work with. This one will simply trigger an `alert` when the page loads.

1. Download [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.7.html) so you're not adding BOM (Byte Order Marks) if you're running a Microsoft operating system.
2. Save the following code as `example.xhtml`.
3. Modify as needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Default Test Template</title>
<script defer="true" type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function(event)
{
 alert('JavaScript is enabled');
}
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">

body {background-color: #000; color: #fff;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Default Test Template</h1>

</body>
</html>
```